# Piping output of subprocess.Popen to files

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I need to launch a number of long-running processes with `subprocess.Popen`, and would like to have the `stdout` and `stderr` from each automatically piped to separate log files. Each process will run simultaneously for several minutes, and I want two log files (`stdout` and `stderr`) **per process** to be written to as the processes run.

Do I need to continually call `p.communicate()` on each process in a loop in order to update each log file, or is there some way to invoke the original `Popen` command so that `stdout` and `stderr` are automatically streamed to open file handles?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen),

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the
>   executed programs’ standard input,
>   standard output and standard error
>   file handles, respectively. Valid
>   values are PIPE, an existing file
>   descriptor (a positive integer), an
>   existing file object, and None.

So just pass the open-for-writing file objects as named arguments `stdout=` and `stderr=` and you should be fine!

Comment: Thanks. I could have swore I tried that before and got an error, but that's exactly what I was hoping would work.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I am simultaneously running two processes and save the stdout and stderr from both into one log file. If the output gets too big, one of the subprocesses hangs; don't know which. I can't use formatting in a comment so I'll append an "answer" below.

Answer (score 94):

You can pass `stdout` and `stderr` as parameters to `Popen()`

```
subprocess.Popen(self, args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None,
                 stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False,
                 cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, 
                 creationflags=0)
```

For example

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> with open("stdout.txt","wb") as out, open("stderr.txt","wb") as err:
...    subprocess.Popen("ls",stdout=out,stderr=err)
... 
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xa3519ec>
>>>
```

Comment: Woa! I had no idea you could chain `open`s like that in a context manager.  #mindblown

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

`with open("server.log", "wb") as out:
    sp.call(server_cmd, stdout = out)`

Comment: Why does it have to be "wb"? Is there anyway to force the output to be unicode?

Comment: You can use the encode argument with open like so with open("abc.txt","wb",encoding="utf-8") as file_object

Comment: How long do those filehandles remain valid? If the `with` scope closes, but the subprocess is still running beyond that, do the file handles remain valid until the subprocess terminates? Do they then automatically close?

Comment: @davidA, the file handles close at the end of the with block. Whatever is done with the Popen object should occur within the with block

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Does it though? I've tried running `subprocess.Popen("sleep 30 && echo OK", shell=True, stdout=f)` within a `with` block and it worked just fine, even though the file was closed before the process actually printed to `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

I am simultaneously running two subprocesses, and saving the output from both into a single log file. I have also built in a timeout to handle hung subprocesses. When the output gets too big, the timeout always triggers, and none of the stdout from either subprocess gets saved to the log file. The answer posed by Alex above does not solve it.

```
# Currently open log file.
log = None

# If we send stdout to subprocess.PIPE, the tests with lots of output fill up the pipe and
# make the script hang. So, write the subprocess's stdout directly to the log file.
def run(cmd, logfile):
   #print os.getcwd()
   #print ("Running test: %s" % cmd)
   global log
   p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines = True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=logfile)
   log = logfile
   return p


# To make a subprocess capable of timing out
class Alarm(Exception):
   pass

def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
   log.flush()
   raise Alarm


####
## This function runs a given command with the given flags, and records the
## results in a log file. 
####
def runTest(cmd_path, flags, name):

  log = open(name, 'w')

  print >> log, "header"
  log.flush()

  cmd1_ret = run(cmd_path + "command1 " + flags, log)
  log.flush()
  cmd2_ret = run(cmd_path + "command2", log)
  #log.flush()
  sys.stdout.flush()

  start_timer = time.time()  # time how long this took to finish

  signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
  signal.alarm(5)  #seconds

  try:
    cmd1_ret.communicate()

  except Alarm:
    print "myScript.py: Oops, taking too long!"
    kill_string = ("kill -9 %d" % cmd1_ret.pid)
    os.system(kill_string)
    kill_string = ("kill -9 %d" % cmd2_ret.pid)
    os.system(kill_string)
    #sys.exit()

  end_timer = time.time()
  print >> log, "closing message"

  log.close()
```

Comment: `shell=True` is not recommended to use

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer of Alex Martelli I've created a small example which works for me.

#### runit.sh

Program which is executed:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 5
ls -la
sleep 5
ls -la /Users
sleep 5
echo "Hello World!!"
```

#### Detaching a process in Python

```py
import os
from subprocess import Popen
import shlex


if __name__ == "__main__":

    fhout = open(f'{os.getcwd()}/stdout.log', 'w')
    fherr = open(f'{os.getcwd()}/stderr.log', 'w')
    command = shlex.split(f"{os.getcwd()}/runit.sh")
    p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=fhout, stderr=fherr, text=True, close_fds=True)

    pid = p.pid

    print(f'PID of the process is: {pid}')
```