# Redirecting Output of PIPE to a FILE in python

Tags: python, pipe, stdout

Following code is to redirect the output of the Pipe to a file "CONTENT" and it has some content, I want to overwrite it with output of "sort CONTENT1 | uniq "....
But I'm not able overwrite it and also i don't know weather following code is redirecting to CONTENT(ie correct or not) or not. Please help me out....

```
f1=open('CONTENT','w')      
sys.stdout=f1  
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "CONTENT1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["uniq"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
p1.stdout.close()  
p2.communicate()   
sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: Why not direct `p2` stdout *directly* to `f1`? `stdout=f1`.

Comment: can show me that line....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [piping output of subprocess.Popen to files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331339/piping-output-of-subprocess-popen-to-files)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not really, this question is about connecting two processes with a pipe, then passing the final output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can catch the output of the first process and pass it to the second, which will then write its output to the file:

```
import subprocess
with open('CONTENT','w') as f1:
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "CONTENT1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(["uniq"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=f1)
  p1_out = p1.communicate()[0] # catch output
  p2.communicate(p1_out)       # pass input
```

You should not tinker with `sys.stdout` at all. Note that you need one
call to the method `communicate` for each process. Note also that
`communicate()` will buffer all output of `p1` before it is passed to
`p2`.

Here is how you can pass the output of `p1` line-by-line to `p2`:

```
import subprocess
with open('CONTENT','w') as f1:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "CONTENT1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(["uniq"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=f1)
    out_line = p1.stdout.readline()
    while out_line:
        p2.stdin.write(out_line)
        out_line = p1.stdout.readline()
```

The cleanest way to do the pipe would be the following:

```
import subprocess
with open('CONTENT','w') as f1:
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "CONTENT1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(["uniq"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f1)
  p1.stdout.close()
```

Alternatively, of course, you could just use the facilities of the
shell, which is just made for these tasks:

```
import subprocess
with open('CONTENT','w') as f1:
    p = subprocess.Popen("sort CONTENT1 | uniq", shell=True,
                         stdout=f1)
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But it is not overwriting CONTENT file rather it is appending.....?

Comment: `open('CONTENT','w')` should open the file `CONTENT` for writing, overwriting everything that is in it. To append you would need `open('CONTENT','a')`.