# Cannot successfully redirect stdout from Popen to temp file

Tags: python, subprocess, io-redirection, temporary-files

The title says it all, really. Currently running Python 2.7.8, using `subprocess32`. Minimum reproducing snippet, copied directly from the REPL:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Aug 14 2014, 13:26:38)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> import subprocess32 as subp
>>> tfil = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
>>> tfil
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x7f79dcf158a0>
>>> proc = subp.Popen(['ls', '-al'], stdout=tfil, stderr=subp.STDOUT)
>>> proc
<subprocess32.Popen object at 0x7f79dcf04a50>
>>> proc.wait()
0
>>> tfil.read()
''
>>>
```

Changes to the code that made no difference in the result, in any combination:

- Using `subprocess` instead of `subprocess32`
- Using `NamedTemporaryFile` instead of `TemporaryFile`
- Setting `bufsize=0` on either or both of `tfil` and `proc`
- If I try `subp.Popen(['ls', '-al'], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subp.STDOUT)`, the output redirects to the terminal just fine - but I need to capture it somewhere else, I can't just mix it together with actual terminal output. Redirecting `sys.stdout` to the temp file, and then setting it back after the process is done, doesn't work either.

I need to do this because the command I want to use in the actual non-minimal-example program (`qacct -j`) has an output that's too big for `subprocess.PIPE`, raising a `MemoryError` (no further details).

The most relevant existing question I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331339/piping-output-of-subprocess-popen-to-files), but that didn't actually help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is properly written to, but your `tfil.read()` command will start reading at the point where the last write happened, so it will return nothing. You need to call `tfil.seek(0)` first.