# python subprocess no such file

Tags: python, subprocess, file-not-found

In python, when I execute the commands

```
cmd = ['head', '-7', 'rres17.txt', '>', 'x']
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

I get the error message

```
head: cannot open ‘>’ for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘x’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

When I execute the command

```
cmd = "head -7 rres17.txt > x"
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

I get the error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'head -7 rres17.txt > x'
```

I'm using python version 3.5.2.  How do I get subprocess to correctly
execute this command, the way the documentation seems to indicate that it should?  Thanks.

EDIT:

The following commands worked:

```
cmd = ['head', '-7', 'rres17.txt']
with open("x", "wb") as out: subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out)
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Try changing 'rres17.txt' to your full path.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I get the same error when I changed to the full path.

Comment: `>` syntax is something the shell processes, not something that should actually make its way into the executed command.

Comment: You need to use `subprocess`'s output redirection facilities, not shell syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot redirect stdout to a file like this, you need to use `subprocess.run` and redirect to a pipe.

See [piping output of subprocess.Popen to files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2331339/1513933)

For instance:

```
import subprocess
import io

with io.open('x', mode='wb') as fd:
    subprocess.run(['head', '-7', 'rres17.txt'], stdout=fd)
```

Comment: I still get the same kind of error .  Using [code] with open("x", "wb") as out: subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out) `code` and removing the shell redirection gives the same error.