# python subprocess call not working with "echo" linux command

Tags: python, linux, command, subprocess, echo

to simplify the problem, I want to use subprocess.call to write a simple string such as "abc" into a dummy file called  "test"

```
subprocess.call(["echo", "abc", ">", "/data/test"])
```

the result is not as expected: it outputs on the console

> abc > /data/test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output with subprocess in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965159/608639) and [Piping output of subprocess.Popen to files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2331339/608639)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer on the dupe is not the best one, there's another with more votes

Comment: ok. i undersatnd it is just not possible with subprocess.call to redirect output.