# How to run executable in Python 3 while passing two inputs to the prompt and redirecting output to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Here are the list of task I would like to automate and capture the output into a text file using Python 3:

1. Run the executable `auth_bin`
2. Asks for entering password
3. After entering the password from keyboard, it gives an output on the terminal
4. Asks for choosing a number
5. Generates a file on disk

I can automate inputing my password and the choice number with the following code, but cannot capture the output in step#3.

```
import subprocess
from getpass import getpass

choice_num = "5"
mypass = getpass('Enter your password: ')
subprocess.run(auth_binary, input="\n".join([mypass, choice_num]), text=True)
```

How can I capture screen output into a text file?

BTW, I can give two inputs (step# 2 and 4) from the keyboard and save the screen output from my Mac terminal this way:

`auth_bin 2>&1 | tee output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To capture the stream of a process, you can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and take advantage of the 'stdout' and 'stderr' arguments to capture the outputs and errors.

There's a [good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2331376/11845677) on how to save these to a file with Python 3.

Hope this solution suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks @A.Ber for your answer. I tried it, but it does not prompt me for the password. Seems like the password prompt goes into the captured file. I experimented with `subprocess.run` and took the output into a variable. I can serve my purpose but needs some extra cleanup.